# get access to a file of another PC through NSURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I can access to my local file through NSURL by using:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/Users/user/Desktop/lucky_numbers.json"]];
```

But I need to get access of a file of another PC.
I tried:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://foyzulkarim:000000@192.168.1.48/localhost/Users/foyzulkarim/Desktop/lucky_numbers.json"]];
```

and

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://192.168.1.48/localhost/Users/foyzulkarim/Desktop/lucky_numbers.json"]];
```

and

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://Foyzul-Karims-MacBook.local/localhost/Users/foyzulkarim/Desktop/lucky_numbers.json"]];

But Error shows `NSURLError domain code -1100`

Please help me if anyone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to my local file through NSURL by using:  `NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://192.168.1.48/localhost/Volumes/foyzulkarim/Desktop/lucky_numbers.json"]];`

but, to do this you have to first connect with that PC manually.

Answer (score 2):

I doesn't work that way. The `file:` URI scheme only supports local file access, not remote. For remote access you need a real network protocol like HTTP or FTP and thus a server on the remote site.

Comment: yap..you are right.But I want to access local files. that's why I use file: URL. Can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: "local" in this context means: files on the same machine that your programs run on. What you want is *remote* access. The files you want to access are on another machine, and thus remote. As I said, for that you need some kind of server running on the remote machine that speaks a protocol iOS understands (like HTTP) and that is configured to allow access to another computer (the one your program runs on). You cannot use `file:` URIs for anything else than accessing files on the very same machine that the program runs on.